# Gradle looking for POM instead of ZIP

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

Here's a part of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.(...)/artifactory/jcenter/"
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUsername
            password artifactoryPassword
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.(...)/artifactory/libs-release-local/"
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUsername
            password artifactoryPassword
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    [amq, amqBundles, amqExtensions]
}

dependencies {
    amq(group: 'com.redhat', name: 'amq-broker', version: '7.10.0', ext: 'zip')
    amqBundles(group: "org.postgresql", name: "postgresql", version: "42.2.14", ext: "jar")
    amqExtensions(group: "biz.paluch.logging", name: "logstash-gelf", version: "1.14.1", ext: "jar")
}

(...)

task extractAmq(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.amq.files
    into "$buildDir/software/amq"
}
```

And here's the error I get when I run "gradle help":

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'installer'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':amq'.
   > Could not find com.redhat:amq-broker:7.10.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://artifactory.(...)/artifactory/jcenter/com/redhat/amq-broker/7.10.0/amq-broker-7.10.0.pom
       - https://artifactory.(...)/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/redhat/amq-broker/7.10.0/amq-broker-7.10.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

It fails at the "from configurations.amq.files" line.

Why is it looking for a .pom instead of .zip and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added metadataSources to the repositories like so:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.(...)/artifactory/jcenter/"
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUsername
            password artifactoryPassword
        }
        metadataSources{
            artifact()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.(...)/artifactory/libs-release-local/"
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUsername
            password artifactoryPassword
        }
        metadataSources{
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
```

and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).